# C++ templates, resolve undefined type in compile-time

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a template class, `IO<T>` and another template class `MembershipFunction<T>`. I need to have a vector of `MembershipFunction<T>*`s in my `IO` thing, and also a `std::map`  from `std::string` to `MembershipFunction<T>*`. For me, it's impossible to remember things in such a complex code. Especially when working with iterators. So I tried to add some `typedef`s to `IO`. But sounds like the compiler is not able to see nested templates. Errors are listed below.

What should I do to overcome?

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include "membership_function.h" // for the love of god! 
                                 // MembershipFunction is defined there!
#include "FFIS_global.h"


template <typename T>
class DLL_SHARED_EXPORT IO
{
private:
    typedef std::pair<std::string,  MembershipFunction<T>* > MapEntry; // (1)
    typedef std::map<std::string, MembershipFunction<T>* > Map; // (2)
    typedef std::vector<const MembershipFunction<T>* > Vector; // (3)
    // And so on...
```

These are errors:

```
(1) error: 'MembershipFunction' was not declared in this scope
(1) error: template argument 2 is invalid
(1) error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
(2 and 3): same errors
```

**Edit:**

This is code for `MembershipFunction`

```
template <typename T>
class DLL_SHARED_EXPORT MembershipFunction
{
public:
    virtual T value(const T& input) const{return T();}
    virtual void setImplicationMethod(const typename  MFIS<T>::Implication& method);
};
```

Comment: did u include the MembershipFunction .h file?

Comment: What do you mean with nested typedef? Please show a minimal working example.

Comment: @rhalbersma well, that was nested template. And yes, it's not nested! I mean using a template class inside another... I don't know what's the correct term for that.

Comment: The first error says 'not defined in this scope'. So in which scope (class or namespace) is `MembershipFunction` defined?

Comment: @rhalbersma Both are defined in `FFIS` namespace and I included `mf.h` which `MembershipFunction` is defined in. I tried removing template from `MembershipFunction` (make it a normal class with `int` instead of `T`) There was no error. I thinks it's matter of templates, not scope

Comment: How is the macro `DLL_SHARED_EXPORT` defined?

Comment: Also, what's in FFIS_global.h?

Comment: @Philipp They are macros used to export symbols for dlls in windows. see http://pastebin.com/eCJf45Nd

Comment: @sorush-r templated code needs to be in the header. Are you sure you didn't put some of the code in a cpp file? and did you include the namespaces correctly ?

Comment: @YochaiTimmer I put the definition in cpp files and included that file at the end of header, in the case that compiler don't implement the `export` keyword. And yes, I used the namespace correctly. I found the problem and solved it. That was circular inclusion of headers. see the comment on last answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I copy/pasted your code and it compiles fine with gcc. There is nothing wrong with your template usage. The compiler error says it hasn't seen the type before. I don't care that you include the file, the compiler doesn't see the full definition for some reason. A forward declaration may not be enough. It's also unclear what that DLL_SHARED_EXPORT is, I suspect that might be the culprit.

Before you downvote me, compile this and see for yourself:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class  MembershipFunction
{
public:
    virtual T value(const T& input) const{return T();}
    //virtual void setImplicationMethod(const typename  MFIS<T>::Implication& method);
};


template <typename T>
class IO
{
private:
    typedef std::pair<std::string,  MembershipFunction<T>* > MapEntry; // (1)
    typedef std::map<std::string, MembershipFunction<T>* > Map; // (2)
    typedef std::vector<const MembershipFunction<T>* > Vector; // (3)
};
```

Comment: First of all, I didn't downwote any answer. Second, No need to test. I know it's working! IT SHOULD WORK. I'm struggling to find *why* my code is not compiling. Before using the code in a third class, everything compiled nicely. Then I added a list of `IO` objects to a class named `Aggregator<T>` (an empty class) and errors occurred.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was circular inclusion. Though It's not solved yet! See the last comment on Mark's answer

Answer (score -1):

You have to define `MembershipFunction` before it can be used in `IO`, just make sure it comes first. If they're in separate files then `#include` the one in the other.

Comment: @sorush-r, there's nothing in your question to indicate that you did, and the error messages imply otherwise. "was not declared in this scope" means that the class name isn't recognized, either it isn't defined at all or it's defined in the wrong namespace.

Comment: So, I'm sure that I included corresponding header and both classes are in same namespace. What else I should take care of?

Comment: @sorush-r, the only other thing I can think of is that `#if` include guards in `membership_function.h` are preventing it from being seen. Does it `#include` any other files?

Comment: Which `#if` you mean? There is only one `#ifndef` in the beginning (as usual as all C++ headers) and one for including .cpp file. See the code: http://pastebin.com/79fCfsiU

Comment: Oops! That was a simple circular inclusion. `mfis.h` includes `io.h`, `io.h` includes `mf.h` and `mf.h` includes `mfis.h`. Normally I remove include statement from `mfis.h` and forward declare `IO` there. but here I don't know what to do with template...